# Gradle build error: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript, gradlew

Please for days now, I have been trying to try with nativescript. All my installation went all fine but at the point of xecuting tns run android --emulator, it gives me the bellow error:

MiC@USER MINGW32 ~/Android-projects/HelloWorld
$ tns run android
Searching for devices...
Skipping prepare.
Building project...
Gradle build...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha7.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha7.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.4.0-alpha7/gradle-2.4.0-alpha7.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.4.0-alpha7/gradle-2.4.0-alpha7.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.98.101:5555. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

Please, what do I do to rectify this error?

Thank you for your response in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the android folder in your project's platform folder.
and then run `tns run android`

Comment: Thank you shiva. After a try, below is the error i got again:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx16384M

Comment: It appears like you are using 32bit jdk. Have you tried using 64bit jdk?

Comment: Are you saying I should install 64bit jdk on 32bit OS?

Comment: In that case, You should switch to 64bit os first.